# Javascript Output results with input data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a newbie to *javascript*, I am making a simple script which will show appended link with the data entered in input field, Basically it should get the data from `input` field and generate link with data being submitted in input field.

Similar to the example below

Input: tony@mail.com ...> after clicking Send button

processing....

Output link: www.domain.com/route.php?email=tony@mail.com

I found this code similar to mine but it wont works like i am looking for.

```
<p>Enter your email or User ID 
<input type="text" name="foo" id="foosite" value="" />
<a href="#"
   onclick="this.href = ('http://' + document.getElementById('foosite').value + 'www.domain.com/route.php?email=')"
   target="_blank">send</a>
```

Is that possible in *javascript* to make a script like this which will generate output without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your JS logic from your HTML

**HTML**

```
<p>Enter your email or User ID 
    <input type="text" name="foo" id="foosite" value="" />
</p>
<a href="#" id='link' target="_blank">send</a>
<div id="url_value"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var a = document.getElementById('link')
a.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = document.getElementById('foosite').value;
    var route = "http://www.domain.com/route.php?email=" + value + ',  ';
    var data = "http://www.domain.com/data.php?email=" + value + ',  ';
    var form = "http://www.domain.com/form.php?email=" + value;

    document.getElementById('url_value').innerHTML = route + data + form
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b2Zcr/3/)**

Comment: Thank you so much for your good answer, But i want it to show result on page. not to go to the link upon send. Is it possible to show output link on page??

Comment: @dcodessmith Cool! This is what i am looking for, One last question. Is it possible to generate multiple output links from one input? eg.

http://www.domain.com/route.php?email=
http://www.domain.com/data.php?email=
http://www.domain.com/form.php?email=

Thanks!

Comment: Yes sure! I am making it answered :) Thank you so much. can you please tell how to make for multiple output links?

Answer (score 1):

You have the getelement in the wrong place. It should be like this if you want to do it that way.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" id="foosite1" value="" />
<a href="#" onclick="this.href = ('http://www.domain.com/route.php?email=' + document.getElementById('foosite1').value)" target="_blank">send</a>

<input type="text" name="foo" id="foosite2" value="" />
<a href="#" onclick="this.href = ('http://www.domain.com/route.php?email=' + document.getElementById('foosite2').value)" target="_blank">send</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bowenac/J2Mc5/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can add form to your html code and send data to server using form submit, in this case you can change the action of the form before submit to custom link.

```
<form name="form1" action="" onSubmit="onsubmit(this)">
    <p>
        Enter your email or User ID
        <input type="text" name="foo" id="foosite" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </p>
 </form>


 <script>
   function onsubmit(form)
   {  
    //change the action of the form to your link.
     form.submit();
   }
  </script>
```